# Como passar parâmetros para os métodos da minha classe de domínio

Tags: ddd

Seguindo os patterns definidos no DDD tenho minha classe de domínio não anêmica com dados e comportamentos e uma delas é meu agregador, até aqui tudo ok.

Minha dúvida é quando tenho muitos dados que foram passados por um usuário para criar ou atualizar essa entidade meu método fica com muitos parâmetros.

Uma maneira de resolver isso seria encapsulando esses parâmetros em uma classe, mas essa classe para ser utilizada no meu domínio teria que fazer parte dele, mas fica estranho criar essa classe sendo que ela não representa um objeto de valor, entidade ou nada parecido sendo um simples DTO.

E também não sei se é correto eu criar um desses objetos, como um objeto de valor fora do meu agregador, até onde entendi é responsabilidade dele criar todos os "filhos" que compõe o mesmo.

Então existe alguma forma de passar essa lista de parâmetros de uma maneira melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sei se entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas acho que posso ajudar.
Primeiramente sobre criar o DTO, você pode criar um DTO sempre que achar necessário,pois o DTO serve para isso mesmo, para representar uma estrutura que pode ser de um dado temporário. É apenas uma visão de alguns dados arranjados naquela estrutura.
Segundo acredito que na pergunta mesmo, você já respondeu. Ao invés de na assinatura do método você ter que receber vários parâmetros, você recebe um array penas, contendo N parâmetros.
Ex:  Ao invés de ficar assim metodo(param1, param2, param3 ....)
você faria assim metodo(params[])
e dentro do seu método você iteraria 'params' e farias as devidas validações, e depois a manipulação necessária

caso não tenha te respondido,poderia exemplificar melhor sua dúvida?

Comment: Na minha visão não faz sentido criar um DTO no meu domínio, resumindo minha dúvida seria se tem uma alternativa em eu criar um value object que pertence a um aggregate fora dele para passar como parâmetro para meu domínio.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/net-core-microservice-domain-model

Aqui tem um exemplo onde ele adiciona um produto no carrinho mas passa apenas os primitios deixando a criação para a classe de dominio, mas no meu caso eu tenho muitos atributos para passar, como um mapa e não consigo passar sem criar um objeto